# registerMailPartials() and registerMailLayouts()

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I want to register my own e-mail layout at octobercms. Template registration works great. However, the use of registerMailLayouts and registerMailPartials methods does not work. I have no errors or the expected result. In the System\Classes\PluginBase class, there are no registerMailLayouts and registerMailPartials method.

I use the documentation:
https://octobercms.com/docs/services/mail#mail-template-registration

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality was introduced in https://github.com/octobercms/october/pull/3850. It is still in the develop branch, it hasn't been added to master yet. See https://octobercms.com/docs/console/commands#console-install-composer for how to switch your project to use the develop branch so that you can always have the latest additions and bug fixes available.